# How to change object in NSArray

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I have two `NSArray`s and I would like to change one object in the first `NSArray` with another object in the second `NSArray`.

This is what I tried to do, but with no luck:

```
[[arrrndwords objectsinindex:i] replace object in index:1 with:[arrword indexinobject:rndnum]];
```

It throws me out of the app when I run it.

Answer (score 23):

The method you are looking for is:

```
- (void)replaceObjectsAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes withObjects:(NSArray *)objects
```

but it is not available to `NSArray` because it's immutable, you should use a `NSMutableArray`.

```
[array replaceObjectsAtIndex:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1] withObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObject:yourObject]]
```

Comment: And it should be noted that an NSArray can be converted to an NSMutableArray with `mutableCopy` or any one of several other techniques.